# Why do systems keep oscillating after a small disturbance?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

I have seen many questions in the famous Indian "JEE exam" which involves a system being given a small disturbance and then oscillating in simple harmonic motion due to it.

Examples:

1. > A horizontal wire AB which is free to move in a vertical pane and carries a steady current is in equilibrium at a height $d$ over another parallel long wire CD, which is fixed in a figure. Show that when AB is slightly depressed and released, it executes simple harmonic motion. Then Find the period of oscillations.
2. > A highly rigid cubical block A of small mass $M$ and side $L$ is fixed rigidly on to another cubical block B of the same dimensions and of low modulus of rigidity $η$ such that the lower face of A completely covers the upper face of B. The lower face of B is rigidly held on a horizontal surface. A small force $F$ is applied perpendicular to one of a sides faces of A. After the force is withdrawn, block A executes small oscillations, the time period of which is given by...

Now my question about these questions:

In all of these questions, the part I don't understand is how they keep oscillating. Like I can understand gravity pulling down for the first case, but then why does it go back up? And in the second case, why does the block oscillate back and forth on the big block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you start with some pretty generic potential $V(x)$, then the equilibrium position is that the bottom of this potential, where $\frac{dV}{dx}=0$.  This is also the point where the force $F=0$ since $F=-\frac{dV}{dx}$.  Suppose for simplicity the equilibrium position is near $x=a$.  Then expanding $V$ about this equilibrium position gives
\begin{align}
V(x)&\approx V(a)+ (x-a)\frac{dV}{dx}\Bigl\vert_{x=a}+\frac{1}{2}(x-a)^2\frac{d^2 V}{dx^2}\Bigl\vert_{x=a}+\ldots \, , \tag{1}\\
&= V(a)+\frac{1}{2}k (x-a)^2
\end{align}
where $k=V^{\prime\prime}(a)$, and $x-a$ is the displacement from the equilibrium position.  This holds because *by definition* of the equilibrium position, there is no force there, or $\frac{dV}{dx}=0$ at that point.

Thus, for small displacements, the potential is harmonic (up to an inessential constant in the potential energy) and the force near this equilibrium position is precisely the same as the force from a spring of spring constant $k$.

Note that the expansion in (1) continues with terms in $(x-a)^3$ but if $x-a$ is small then these are usually neglected a smaller than the dominant contribution in $(x-a)^2$.  In fact, comparing the size of the cubic term with that size of the quadratic term is useful in establishing the notion of a “small” displacement: it is precisely a displacement so that this cubic term can be safely neglected.

Comment: hmm what bothers me here is like the second position derivative of potential is the derivative of force with potential. For harmonic oscillator, we need force proportional to distance; not derivative of force proportional to distance

Comment: The potential is approximately $V(a)+\frac{1}{2}k(x-a)^2$.  The force is negative of derivative of the potential so proportional to $(x-a)$ and thus equal to $0$ when $x=a$, i.e. at the equilibrium position.

Answer (score 5):

"Why" questions in physics are tricky.  The end all answer is "things do what they will do, because that's what they will do."  If you want more than that, you have to specify what kind of modeling you want to describe the physics with.  And, in general, if you can do that then you typically don't have the question.  It's a frustrating Catch 22.

Trying to stay as general as possible, virtually all things described as oscillation can be approached by looking at energy being converted from one form to another.  The most common pattern is a shift between kinetic and potential energies.  If you do something like push on the wire in the first example, intuitively you must be moving the wire into a position which has more potential energy.  You know this because the wire didn't go there on its own, and intuitively you can tell the wire is pushing back, trying to move towards equilibrium (the reason for this force would be a magnetic field repelling it due the current flow).  So thus it should be expected that, when you let go, the wire will begin converting that potential energy into kinetic, moving towards an equilibrium point.

However, in systems that oscillate, when you get back to the initial position, you still have a large velocity.  In fact, you can show that because you've transferred as much potential energy into kinetic as you can, it's actually at its fastest at this point!  It overshooots, and begins transfering kinetic energy into potential, until it comes to a stop on the other side, and starts moving back.

The best tool I know of to visualize this sort of thing is a phase space diagram.  Phase space diagrams capture all of the degrees of freedom in a system.  For these systems, that's not only the position but the velocity as well.  A simple harmonic oscillator will look like the diagram on the right:
[image: Phase diagram for a pendulum]

When you visualize both position and velocity, you see a shape that makes it more obvious that oscillation is occurring.

Some of what makes this unintuitive is that we typically don't expect objects to do this.  Most real life systems are *damped*, which means something is drawing energy out of it (typically converting it to heat as mechanical bonds are bent and flexed).  Most systems are so heavily damped that we don't even observe anything that looks oscilatory.  However, some real systems do and they show us what a more realistic phase space diagram looks like:
[image: Phase diagram with a focus]
In this phase diagram, one may have pushed on the wire to move it into the end point at the top of this diagram and then let go.  It then transfers kinetic and potential energy back and forth, but each time a little of that energy is lost to heat.  Eventually the wire settles back down where you expect it, in its natural resting spot.

Much of the wording in these questions is centered around getting as close to the ideal case as possible.  No real systems can actually oscillate forever without energy input, and they didn't want to ask you to work on an unrealistic ideal system, so they chose a real system whose description gets it as close to the ideal as possible.

In America, we have a phrase "assume the cow is spherical."  It's a reference to a physics problem calculating the trajectory of a cow flung by a catapult in Monte Python and the Holy Grail.  Of course, in the real world, the ballistic properties of a cow are enormously complex, so for this problem, the students were told to assume the cow was spherical (as they had been taught how to do ballistic coefficients for spheres already).  It was such a humorous wording that the story of this question spread far and wide.  Noways it's used as a very tongue-in-cheek way of saying "don't worry about the reality here... just focus on the ideal models"

It looks like this test is trying very hard to not say "assume the cow is spherical," while still wording the questions to get as close to that ideal as possible, so that you use the right equations to demonstrate your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Cort Ammon's answer is very good, here is an intuitive way to think about his answer.

Consider the pendulum in his example.  When you lift it to the right side and let it go, gravity starts pulling it down.  Due to the tension in the wire, it picks up some horizontal velocity and swings to the left.  You may think it should just stop at the bottom.  But if you think about it a little further, you can see why this is not the case.  At the bottom of the swing, the pendulum has velocity to the left.  Gravity is pulling straight down.  The tension in the wire is pulling straight up.  What force could act on the pendulum to slow it to a stop at the bottom?  There isn't one.  There is no force pulling to the right.  Only once the pendulum has started to move up to the left will the tension in the wire have a horizontal component pulling to the right.  In short, the reason kinematic systems oscillate is inertia.

Answer (score 0):

When a potential is given to a system due to a tiny displacement, the object would want to return to equilibrium spot so that it'd reduce the potential. However, it'd overshoot the equilibrium as it'd have gained some velocity because of the continually decreasing potential would continuously convert to kinetic energy in the motion.

For the reason the object does not 'exit' the system, it is the fact that the constraint of the system ( ex: rigid attachment of small block in q.2), keeps the body from exiting the system. It is the constraint that directs the object back into equilibrium.

Answer (score 0):

It is all simple to understand. The oscillations occur because of something called restoring force. When disturbed from equilibrium position and released, it experiences a restoring force. It then overshoots the equilibrium on the other side when the restoring force changes direction to bring it back to equilibrium. This process continues and contributes to oscillations.